# Efficient bounded biased random number generator

Tags: java, algorithm, math, statistics

**Context**

Part of the Population-Based Incremental Learning (PBIL) algorithm is to calculate many biased random bits. The bias of each bit is determined by a corresponding double in the range 0.0-1.0.

For each bit a non-biased random double in the range 0.0-1.0 is compared with the bias. If the random double generated is less than the bias the bit is set to 0 else 1.

After the biased sequence of bits is generated the bits are converted to doubles within various ranges.

**Question**

I would like to generate a biased double within a range directly. That is without manipulating each bit in the double representation. Each double would then have a single variable which determined the bias (not one for each bit). As previously each double also has a minimum and maximum constant which determine the lower and upper bounds of the random double.

The following example produces an acceptable distribution. However it would be nice to solve the problem without a potentially endless while loop.

```
public double getBiasedRandom(double bias, double min, double max) {
    double rndBiased;
    double variance = (max-min)*0.3;

    do {
         rndBiased = bias + (random.nextGaussian() * variance);
    } while(rndBiased < min && rndBiased <= max);

    return rndBiased;
}
```

Solutions don't have to return an identical distribution, but all values within the bounds must be possible outcomes for any bias. Also values closer to the bias should be more likely than values further away. I don't know by how much. Ideally it would be determined by a variable that could be set experimentally. In the above example this variable is the constant 0.3.

I've tried to look into different distributions, but my mathematical skills are insufficient. Also keep in mind that performance is critical and that an approximate, but efficient solution is probably favorable. For the same reason solutions that depend on weighted tables are probably not worth it.

**EDIT:** Added a potential solution inspired by Cristiano Zambon's answer.

Comment: what is the magic missing step in "the bits are converted to either doubles or integers within various ranges"?  that seems important to me.  without that i have no idea what you really want - it would be easy to give an example that technically meets your final requirements, but is hopelessly wrong.

Comment: The conversion of bits to integers or doubles are not important. Just think of the initial bit sequence as the bits of an integer or double array.

Comment: The question is not how to convert a biased bit sequence to integers and doubles, but how to ignore the bit level completely and create biased integers and doubles directly.

Comment: if the integer is just a collection of biased bits (which seems to be how pbil works; i have no idea what you are doing with doubles) then what you are asking makes no sense.  you seem to be confusing biasing how many bits are set with biasing the value of an integer,  the two are not the same.  consider 8 bit integers.  254 and 127 are not close in value but have the same number of bits set, while 127 and 128 are close in value but have very different numbers of bits set.

Comment: PBIL tries to maximize (or minimize) the result of a function (think f(x) = x) that depends on a certain set of variables {x}. The number, type and relations between variables are known, but their values are not. In this case let x be represented by a 8 bit integer. Initially PBIL favors 1 and 0 for each bit equally. But after generating a series of random bits several times and comparing the results of the function it starts to favor certain values of each bit. However the principle should work equally well if the bias  is applied directly to the value x.

Comment: 127 and 128 have similar bit configuration if Gray Code is used. Though PBIL and related evolutionary algorithms works without it too. It's not only the number of bits set that's relevant, but also the position of each bit. Hence all data structures including doubles can be represented this way. Nevertheless the reason I want to ignore the bit level is to reduce the number of biases (currently 1 double per bit) the program has to maintain, and hopefully the lack of bit operations will give an extra speed increase in java.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you just need a function that return a random numbered "centered" on bias and always inside the {min;max} range...

what about:

```
public double getBiasedRandom(double bias, double min, double max) {
    double bias_depth_perc = 0.1;
    double bias_depth_abs = (max - min)*bias_depth_perc;
    double min_bias = bias - bias_depth;
    double max_bias = bias + bias_depth;
    Random tRandom = new Random();

    if (max_bias > max) max_bias = max;
    if (min_bias < min) min_bias = min;

    double variance = (max_bias - min_bias)/2;


    double rndBiased = bias + tRandom .nextGaussian() * aVariance;

    if (rndBiased > max)
       rndBiased = max - (rndBiased - max);

    if (rndBiased < min)
       rndBiased = min + (min - rndBiased);

    return rndBiased;
}
```

practically you get the biased random number simply using a gaussian distribution centered on bias with a variance that you can set to a percentage of range (set in the example to 10% on the row double bias_depth_perc = 0.1).

**EDIT**: changed the behaviour when the bias is close to the boundary and you get a lot of random number outside the limits. Now it simply copy the random generated number inside the boundary with a distance equal to the distance from the limit itself. This ends actually in a simple asymmetrical distribution.

SECOND SOLUTION:
this is a bit more tricky. Here the idea is to always generates a symmetrical random number, and then map the generated number on the right range. For example: if you have:

- min = 0
- max = 1
- bias = 0.1

you firstly generate a random number centered on 0.5 with a variance of your choice:

- rnd = 0.5 tRandom.nextGaussian() * variance;

then, if rnd is > 0.5, you map it into the range {bias; bias + max_bias} with a simple scale moltiplication.
if rnd is < 0.5, you map it into the range {min_bias; bias}.

here is the code:

```
public double getBiasedRandom(double bias, double min, double max) {
    double centered_depth_perc = 0.3;
    double centered_depth_abs = (max - min)*centered_depth_perc;
    double center = 0.5;

    Random tRandom = new Random();  
    double rndCentered = center  + tRandom .nextGaussian() * centered_depth_abs; // generate centered random number. 

    if (rndCentered >= center)
        rndBiased = (rndCentered - center) * (max - bias) + bias;
    else
        rndBiased = bias - (center - rndCentered) * (bias - min);

    // the following two tests will be as more important as centered_depth_perc 
    // get bigger. 
    if (rndBiased > max) 
       rndBiased = max;

    if (rndBiased < min)
       rndBiased = min;

    return rndBiased;
}
```

hope it could help.

Comment: Thanks! From which library do you import RandomGaussian()? Or do you just scale and offset the result from Random.nextGaussian()?

Comment: I used rndBiased = bias+(random.nextGaussian()*variance) and compared a few distributions. First the bias_depth_perc has to be higher in order to make values at the other extreme not just theoretical possibilities. This is expected, but it revealed a problem. If the bias_depth_perc is high many of the values are out of bounds and the max or min values are by far the most likely value, not the bias. I think an asymmetrical and bounded distribution is necessary?

Comment: yes sure you are right...I'm editing my answer fitting the RandomGaussian issue too. Just give me halfen hour :)

Comment: The second solution only works when min=0 and max=1. Anyway the distribution on each side of the bias on its own looks great. However for even moderate biases the probability of bias-0.01 vs bias+0.01 are very different.

Comment: Second solution: i.e. rndCentered = 0.7, min = 5 max = 10 bias = 9, rndBiased = 9.2...why do you say it is only working for {min;max} = {0;1}? rndCentered is calculated in that range, but then rndBiased is scaled to {min;max}. Practically it is creating a gaussian-like distribution centered in bias with difference variances on the two sides in order to have always output into the range. Actually two tests on rndBiased should be added at the end to cancel the few out of range outputs...I'll edit again my post for that, but pls explain  your point.

Comment: Assuming bias=9, min=5 and max=10 with a sample size of 10000. I divide the results in 100 intervals in the range min -> max. The min and max have a size of ~2500 each, while the other intervals varies from ~20 to ~700. I didn't observe this behavior with min=0 and max=1. However assuming bias=0.8, min=0 and max=1 the problem I described earlier is easily seen. The interval to the left of the bias has size ~200 while the interval to the right of the bias has size ~700. The only difference from your code is that tRandom is declared outside the method.

Comment: that just means you choosed a too high value of centered_depth_perc, so you have a too high probability left on the margins...try to decrease it.

Comment: I used the same value for centered_depth_perc in both cases. If it's not a constant it would need to be passed as an argument, and that doesn't solve the problem just moves it. This problem can be solved however by always using the range 0-1 and then scale and offset the result. Do you have any solution to the second problem? I'm pretty sure altering the centered_depth_perc won't remove it.

Comment: can't understand the sentence "This problem can be solved however by always using the range 0-1 and then scale and offset the result"...this is actually what the funcion is doing...it uses interval 0...1 for centered random value and then it scales it to the right range.For the other problem: of course this happens because the funcion maintains the same probability to the two margins indipendently by the bias, so when you have a bias closed to a boundary you will have probability falling down really fast in one side, really slow in the other.

Comment: The method doesn't do it as intended, which can be seen if you compare the distributions. I understand why the other problem happens, but it makes the method unusable.

Comment: this will always happens if you don't want to use a loop as you shown, because gaussian distribution is of course a continuous funcion. If you want to always have the same distribution centered on the bias that just "clip" on the margin, I think there is no other solution that what you did, just generate random numbers until you get one good. Pls note that it is possible this loop become "long", but never "inifinite" as you are not looking for an impossible event.

Comment: I guess the question is more math related than programming related. I know other suitable distributions exists, but I have no idea how to express them as a probability. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: actually I don't think so, as you are looking for a discontinuous distribution I think you have to solve it programmatically. By the way, you are welcome! :)